# How to automate a paypal payment

Tags: php, mysql, paypal

I'm working on a website for my endproject in school, on my website you can buy coins to open presents, but I want to automate the payment. When the customer finished the payment he gets redirected to **success.php** how can I arrange that he will automatically get X amount of coins, after the payment succeed, in his account?

Sorry for using SQL will update it to PDO or mySQLi

Like:

```
if (payment_finished){
sql= UPDATE 'users' SET 'balance' = $boughtamount WHERE username = '$username'
}
```

I use this button for paypal.

```html
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top" style="display: inline-block;">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<table>
<tr align="center"><td><input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Coins">Number of Coins</td></tr><tr><td><select name="os0">
 <option value="25 PackArmy Coins">25 Coins €0,50 EUR</option>
 <option value="40 PackArmy Coins">40 Coins €0,80 EUR</option>
 <option value="50 PackArmy Coins">50 Coins €1,00 EUR</option>
 <option value="75 PackArmy Coins">75 Coins €1,50 EUR</option>
 <option value="100 PackArmy Coins">100 Coins €2,00 EUR</option>
 <option value="500 PackArmy Coins">500 Coins €5,00 EUR</option>
</select> </td></tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
<input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value="-----BEGIN PKCS7-----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-----END PKCS7-----
">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online.">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/nl_NL/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

I hope someone can help me!
Thanks a lot.

Kind Regards,
Julan

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your paypal configuration, when redirected the payment will have a certain status(succes/failed/cancelled/error). You can retrieve that status (and your reference) to automate that process. Usualy you will receive that data via POST while the user is "redirected". A other option would be a  hook where paypal sends data to after user has been redirected. 
In order to know how you can get that data you should read their documentation that fits your configuration/approach on paypal.